# Thunderbird does not honor the configured archive location if it's an IMAP folder on another account

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

I have my mail archives on a local IMAP server (to easily backup them and to not be dependent on a certain mail client)

If I configure another IMAP account to use a folder on this local IMAP account as Archive folder, the mails still get archived to "Archives" on the remote IMAP account.

The documentation suggests, this behaviour "Keep message archives in to set the location of the archive (either in your account's mailbox or in a local folder)" [1]

Is this a bug?

If yes where, should the UI not allow to choose a location where thunderbird can't create an archive or could thunderbird sync to another IMAP account and doesn't for some reason?

Additionally: does anyone have a suggestion for archiving my mails? Can imapsync do this, or are there any scriptable mail client that support multiple accounts?

[1] https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/archived-messages#w_configure-archive-location